# Accessing GeoTransform array from gdal on the Windows command line

Tags: gdal, windows, command-line

I'm using the gdal library via OSGeo for Windows, and I was just wondering how to access the geotransform array for a *.ecw* file?

Comment: What language are you using (python, C#, C++..)? The GeoTransform object is returned with GetGeoTransform() http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDataset.html#af9593cc241e7d140f5f3c4798a43a668 which returns an array of 6 doubles. How far have you got? It would be nice to see what stage you're up to otherwise I might be going over concepts you already know . You will need to have some sort of script or program to access this object, there is not one already. It would also help to know what you want this information for to perhaps suggest alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Michael, I thought there was a command I could simply run in an osgeo command prompt. I'm using C# to run a command line process and extract information about the image. The information will be used to determine the minimum size of a user-provided ecw file to be overlaid on a map as a tiled image. so what I'm looking for in that array is the resolution of the file uploaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be found from `gdalinfo`, except it has three forms:

1. If rotation / shear coefficients (`adfGeoTransform[2]` and `adfGeoTransform[4]`) are zero, the output is simplified:
   `Origin = (%.15f,%.15f)      % adfGeoTransform[0], adfGeoTransform[3]`
   `Pixel Size = (%.15f,%.15f)  % adfGeoTransform[1], adfGeoTransform[5]`
2. If rotation / shear coefficients are non-zero, the full 6-coefficients are shown:
   `GeoTransform =`
     `%.16g, %.16g, %.16g % adfGeoTransform[0], adfGeoTransform[1], adfGeoTransform[2]`
     `%.16g, %.16g, %.16g % adfGeoTransform[3], adfGeoTransform[4], adfGeoTransform[5]`
3. If there is no GeoTransform information, then neither of the above two forms are shown.

The order of coefficients used by GDAL are important, and are [documented here](https://gdal.org/user/raster_data_model.html#affine-geotransform).

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can access GDAL provided you have [the libraries](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp) installed. Reference gdal_csharp.dll. [This tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html) helps a little.

```
using OSGeo.GDAL;
// later inside the class
OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.AllRegister(); // IMPORTANT or nothing will work
// open the ECW dataset in GDAL
OSGeo.GDAL.Dataset pInDS = Gdal.Open(ECW_Path, OSGeo.GDAL.Access.GA_ReadOnly);
// get the GeoTransform from the dataset
double[] pGT= new double[6];
pInDS.GetGeoTransform(pGT);
// use the parameters
CellWidth  = pGT[1];
CellHeight = pGT[5];
OriginX = pGT[0];
OriginY = pGT[3];
// rows and columns for the raster
Rows    = (ulong)pInDS.RasterYSize;
Cols    = (ulong)pInDS.RasterXSize;
```

The GeoTransform object is:

```
adfGeoTransform[0] /* top left x */
adfGeoTransform[1] /* w-e pixel resolution */
adfGeoTransform[2] /* 0 */
adfGeoTransform[3] /* top left y */
adfGeoTransform[4] /* 0 */
adfGeoTransform[5] /* n-s pixel resolution (negative value) */
```

This is the same for every [supported GDAL raster format](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html).

Comment: Thanks Michael! Is there a way to do this manually that you know of? I mean, as you've pointed out, there isn't a command that I can run from the cli, but is there a formula to get at the w-e and n-s pixel values? I was trying to arrive at a value using the corner coordinates, but I'm not sure that's correct. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That was covered in your other question, if you do GDALinfo > TextFile.txt (DOS pipe) you can open it and digest the information. I find it much easier to get it directly, after all you're already in C, why go find GDALinfo.exe and try to grab the info from there when you can get it directly.